# How can i wirelessly deploy on ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios7

I wand to deploy apps wirelessly. I have run script that copy app by ssh on device, but it need to be app compiled for ios device.. but xcode dosn't want tocompile wishout plug-in ipad. Maybe i can emule ipad connection? Or solve this problem another way..//sorry for my perfect english skills

Comment: I don't understand the question not because of your english but because it doesn't have required details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below portals to distribute your app wirelessly.

https://www.testflightapp.com/ or http://www.diawi.com/

Make sure you will build your app .ipa file with proper certificate and provision profile.

You can also make above portal at own too, But It wii be waste of time as they are easily available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look at Apple's [Entreprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) as described here: http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/